# Figure out changed directories in nested structure

Tags: file-copy, recursive

I have a script that needs to parse a directory tree that is around 5 levels deep and sync it into an external service. To minimize the amount of work (there will be a lot of directories on each level), I would like to parse only the directories that were actually changed. Let's assume this structure:

```
- top_level
  - sublevel_1_a
  - sublevel_1_b
      - sublevel_2
          - sublevel_3
```

Now, it should be sufficient to just compare the modification timestamp on the `top_level` directory to figure out that there's nothing to do. Unfortunately, the timestamp doesn't seem to propagate that far. If I'd create a file in `sublevel_3`, only the `sublevel_3` directory will have its timestamp changed. The `sublevel_2` will not indicate that anything happened.

Is it any way to figure out on the `top_level` when was the last time anything happened within any directory below? I'm on RHEL 7.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Did you take a look at `rsync`?

Comment: I don't think `rsync` will be useful to me. I need to read the created files in my app, but only the files that are created (or modified) after a certain timestamp. Can `rsync` tell me which files match that criteria? I don't want to sync the directory with another.

Comment: @Djent Add that (your last comment) to the question as your issue currently seems easily solvable by just running `rsync` on the whole thing.

Comment: 1. you'll have to recurse the directory tree, there's no way of avoiding that.  2. this is one of the things that `find` is for.  you probably want to use something like `find /path/to/top_level/  -type f -mtime -n` (where "n" is the number of days you want files to be newer than).   Alternatively, use `-mmin` or `-newer`.  See `man find` for details.

Comment: 1) adding a file in `sublevel_3` modify `sublevel_3` but not `sublevel_2`. 2) timestamp will not propagate upward, or else `/` would always be at the time of last modification of any file.

Comment: That find example will give you a list of matching files.  To actually do anything with them, you should use either find's `-exec` command OR use `-print0` to output a NUL separated list to pipe into another program (which needs to be capable of understanding NUL-separated filenames - e.g. `find ... -print0 | xargs -0r ...`).   Not using NUL as the filename separator is only safe if you are absolutely certain that none of your file or directory names will ever contain newlines or other whitespace characters (and even then, I would still use NUL).

Comment: @cas But, as I was recently reminded by Stéphane, the `-print0`/`-0` combination is GNU-specific and may not be portable (should be ok in this case, since OP uses RHEL, but still).

Comment: @AdminBee so? as you say, the OP uses RHEL so uses GNU.   Also, GNU tools are pretty much the de-facto standard.   It's the actual standard on Linux (except for some busybox-based tiny distros), and readily available on everything else via either pre-built packages, ports, or compiling from source tarball.  This was true even back in the 90s and is even more true today.

Comment: Thanks, I think `find` may be actually useful here. I was hoping for something a bit faster, as the filesystem is extremely slow so find takes some time to finish. By if there's no other option, then I'll have to live with that.